# Auto layout issue in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I use dynamic height cells for my `UITableView` with this code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QuestionsCell", for: indexPath) as! QuestionsCell

    cell.label1.text = ""
    cell.label2.text = ""
    cell.label1.text = some text from array
    cell.label2.text = some text from array

    cell.label1.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    cell.label1.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.label1.sizeToFit()

    return cell
}
```

Then I've pinned all constraints in Storyboard for each element (top, bottom, leading and trailing). On iPhone everything works fine, but on iPad when I scroll the `UITableView` this is happening (dynamic label height):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

sizeToFit() only makes cell1 as big as it needs to be for the text.
You also need to use automatic height sizing for the table view cells.

In viewDidLoad,

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

You will also want to make sure you have a vertical constraint from your bold label to the "12 days ago" label, to ensure there is always vertical space between them, so they don't overlap.

Comment: I've already added `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and estimated row height and yes, they have some space (1dp) between.

Comment: Try adding top and bottom constraints for "days ago" label with respect to it's above label and bottom view.

Comment: You probably need more space between them. I'd try at least 10pt and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement this delegate method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

if this does not work then check if there is vertical spacing constraints between top textView and bottom textView.

Comment: I've already implemented and added space between them, but it's working like randomly on scrolling